# I can register but cant go further

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

Hi guys i was trying to chceck example app from github who someone made. Heres the link :https://github.com/ysongh/FindSport2Play .I connected it to my own database and connection to database works but i cant register any account. What could be wrong with this?I wanted to check how this app works for educational purposes but its not working when i try to register account i get an error i browser console :net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://localhost:8081/api/users/register

Comment: Don't dump a link, include the code you think is causing the problem *in the question*.

Comment: I wish i know tadman :( it's either the token either the database structure thats why I dropped the link.. hope I get at least where i should focus

Comment: Did your server start cleanly? Were there errors?

Comment: The server started with no err.. and collections created when I register, but when I create an event it doesn't go further with no err msg and nothing shows in my collections